# "can integrated" meaning

Tags: grammar

I saw the following sentence in a paper:

> Filament enables smart devices to blockchain transactions that **can
>   integrated** in different distributed ledger architectures **by use their**
>   Blocklet solution.

I have two questions:

1. I know "*integrate*" is both transitive and intransitive, but, shouldn't it be "*can be integrated*" when it is used after "*can*"?
2. What is the difference between "*by use their ...*" and "*by using their ...*"?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct. It should be "can be integrated". The paper most likely made a typographic error.
2. This again seems to be a typo. "By using their..." is the correct usage.

Hope this helps!